# Mean value in Pandas higher is higher than it should be

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis, mean

I'm trying to compare some NFL concussion stats with some individual player stats from the combine.

```
    dfcomb.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Documents\GWG\NFL Concussion\NFL_concussion\comb.xlsx', index=False)

   # Create a merged df with players that are concussed on dfconc and players that are on dfcomb
    dfcommon = dfcomb.merge(dfconc, on=['nameFull'])
    dfcommon = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\crae1\Documents\GWG\NFL Concussion\NFL_concussion\common.csv')

   # Initialise list of pos
    positions = ['C', 'RB', 'CB', 'LB', 'OG', 'OT', 'QB', 'DT', 'S', 'FB', 'WR', 'TE']

   # Iterate through list and compare height and weight 
    for pos in positions:
        avg = np.mean(dfcomb['heightInches'].where(dfcomb['position'] == pos))
        avgconc = np.mean(dfcommon['heightInches'].where(dfcommon['position'] == pos))
        print('mean height in the NFL for {}s is {} in mean height of concussed players {} in'.format(pos + '\'', avg, avgconc))

    for pos in positions:
        avg = np.mean(dfcomb['weight'].where(dfcomb['position'] == pos))
        avgconc = np.mean(dfcommon['weight'].where(dfcommon['position'] == pos))
        print('mean weight in the NFL for {}s is {} lbs mean weight of concussed players {} lbs'.format(pos +    '\'', avg, avgconc))

   # Create summary df for concussion and NFL groups
    heightavgNFL = dfcomb.groupby('position')['heightInches'].mean
    heightavgdf = dfcommon.groupby('position')['heightInches'].mean
    weightavgNFL = dfcomb.groupby('position')['weight'].mean
    weightavgdf = dfcommon.groupby('position')['weight'].mean


   # Plot height
    bar_width = 0.10
    ax = heightavgNFL().plot(kind='bar', align='edge', title='Mean NFL Height vs Mean Concussed Height', ylabel='Height (in)', xlabel='Position', width=bar_width, figsize=(16,8), color='r',label='NFL')
    heightavgdf().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, align='edge', title='Mean NFL Height vs Mean Concussed Height', ylabel='Height (in)', xlabel='Position', width=-bar_width, figsize=(16,8), color='b',label='Concussion Group')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')

   # Plot weight
    bar_width = 0.10
    ax = weightavgNFL().plot(kind='bar', align='edge', title='Mean NFL Weight vs Mean Concussed Weight',  ylabel='Weight (lbs)', xlabel='Position', width=bar_width, figsize=(16,8), color='r',label='NFL')
    weightavgdf().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, align='edge', title='Mean NFL Weight vs Mean Concussed Weight',     ylabel='Weight (lbs)', xlabel='Position', width=-bar_width, figsize=(16,8), color='b',label='Concussion Group')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

However, when looking at the QB weight from the combine csv file, the weight is a lot higher than expected and this problem only occurs with the QB position. I've had a look through the data and I don't see where it could be getting the higher values from.

[QB Weight Higher than expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtXl.png)

Here is the csv/xlsx file that dfcomb is from:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnmdeJC_g0dLnGzx9LplOkq8iYNJ?e=2NA3WA

Thanks

Comment: this doesn't have to do with answering your question, but from a coding standpoint, you shouldn't need to reuse `for pos in positions:` twice – just put them in the same for loop. with a smaller data set it's fine, but if you have a large data set you'll notice the performance being impacted

Comment: Your right thanks, sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

The `groupby` method does not return sorted data, so your NFL and df data has different order when you add them to the plots. Try this:

```
heightavgNFL = pd.DataFrame(dfcomb.groupby('position')['heightInches'].mean()).sort_values(by=['position'])
heightavgdf = pd.DataFrame(dfcommon.groupby('position')['heightInches'].mean()).sort_values(by=['position'])
weightavgNFL = pd.DataFrame(dfcomb.groupby('position')['weight'].mean()).sort_values(by=['position'])
weightavgdf = pd.DataFrame(dfcommon.groupby('position')['weight'].mean()).sort_values(by=['position'])
```

This works for me:

```
pd.DataFrame(weightavgNFL).join(weightavgdf, lsuffix='_NFL', rsuffix='_df').plot(kind='bar', align='edge', title='Mean NFL Weight vs Mean Concussed Weight',  ylabel='Weight (lbs)', xlabel='Position', width=0.1, figsize=(16,8))
```

Comment: Just tried this and unfortunately the result is the same as before.

Comment: I don't have your `dfcommon` data to confirm it, but I believe you need to make sure the plotted data has the same X axis order for both `weightavgNFL` and `weightavgdf`. The problem isn't that `mean` is wrong, but that you are trying to share the same X axis but the 2 datasets have different orders.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnmdeJC_g0dLnG4BO20jOCt_WXPy?e=WgbyWg, here is the dfcommon data. It seems to me that for some reason it is reading the data in the dfcomb with the OG and QB switched just looking at the NFL graph for both of these positions and I am not sure why.

Comment: Actually I believe your onto something, as the data in dfcomb has players that have the positions K and P in between whereas dfcommon has no K or P players in the df, it seem that the x-axis is 'pushing the data along 2 columns resulting in an inaccurate visual. I'll try removing the K and P players from dfcomb and hopefully that should fix it.

Comment: I wasn't using `.sort_values` correctly. See my edit. Yes, the fact that you have more positions in one dataset is a problem.